# jQuery TableSorter - textExtraction based on external variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

I have a TableSorted table, and in each TD element are five SPAN elements. Four are always hidden, but upon clicking a div outside the table, certain spans are hidden dependent on which div is clicked.

I have the table sorting fine, but what I need is for the textExtraction to grab a different SPAN, depending on the value of the div which has been selected.

I've tried the following to no avail:

```
textExtraction:function(node){
        var filter=$("div.career a.sel").text();
        if(filter=="a"){var theindex=0;}
        if(filter=="b"){var theindex=1;}
        if(filter=="c"){var theindex=2;}
        if(filter=="d"){var theindex=3;}
        if(filter=="e"){var theindex=4;}
        return $(node).find("span").eq(theindex).text();
    }
```

What is the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The `textExtraction` function is only called when tablesorter is initialized or updated. Try triggering an update after the selection has changed.

```
var indexes = 'abcde'.split(''),
    // Is this a select box?
    $sel = $("div.career a.sel").on('change', function(){
        $('table').trigger('update');
    });

$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node){
        // if this is a select, get val(), not text()
        var filter = $sel.val(),
            theindex = $.inArray( filter, indexes );
        return $(node).find("span").eq(theindex).text();
    }
});
```

---

Update: for a link, try this:

```
var indexes = 'abcde'.split(''),
    $careers = $("div.career a").on('click',function(){
        var searcher = $(this).attr("rel");
        $("div.career a").removeClass("sel");
        $(this).addClass("sel");
        $("td.stat span").hide();
        $("td.stat span.career_" + searcher).show();
    });

$('table').tablesorter({
    textExtraction: function(node){
        // find selected
        var filter = $careers.filter('.sel').text(),
        theindex = $.inArray( filter, indexes );
        return $(node).find("span").eq(theindex).text();
    }
});
```

Note: Don't use [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) in jQuery version 1.9+, it was removed.

Comment: Hi, after a bit of playing around I had come to the conclusion that it was because the function wasn't detecting any changes to the page, because it's only called at the start as you say.

The a.sel is just a link, which has a class added (.sel) when it's "selected" (effectively just clicked).

Would you be so kind as to show me how this is best done given that it's not a select box? This is the code which controls the div.career part:

Comment: `$("div.career a").live('click',function(){
var searcher=$(this).attr("rel");
$("div.career a").removeClass("sel");
 $(this).addClass("sel");
 $("td.stat span").hide();
 $("td.stat span.career_"+searcher).css("display","block");
});`

Comment: It appears I've solved it. Thanks @Mottie as it was your clue about triggering the update which has helped.

I added $("table.formguide").trigger("update"); in the onclick function for the a.sel links!